# how to skip every 3rd number from loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops

I want to skip every third number from logic, I tired but I'm not getting the correct way. output should be like this: 0,1,3,4,6,7,9,10,12...

I tried this, but its not working fully.
**

```
for (var item = 0; item < $scope.gridImportData.data.length; item++)
{
  $scope.gridImportData[item] + (($scope.gridImportData[item] - 1) / 3)
}
```

**

Comment: Why not just `item+=3` ?

Comment: try using mod, in java it's `%`, u need to check when `if(item%3!=0){//print item...}` also you may want to exclude 0, so it will be `if(item%3!=0 || item==0)`

Comment: Using the modulus operator (%) you can check if your index is dividable by 3. When the modulus of 3 returns zero, you can skip your logic (that of course implies that your value should be 1-based and not 0-based)

Comment: what do you mean under "skipping"? skip from output(and why did not you show your HTML?)? skip while copying to another array? current code looks meaningless. anyway to skip element based on index you just need to use `if` statement in JS, or `ng-if` directive in your markup

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
    angular.module("a",[]).controller("ac",function($scope){
    $scope.querylist =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
    $scope.newValue=[];
    for (var item = 0; item < $scope.querylist.length; item++){
    if($scope.querylist[item] % 3 == 0 && $scope.querylist[item] !=0)    {
        continue;
       }
      $scope.newValue.push($scope.querylist[item]);
    }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="a" ng-controller="ac">
    <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in newValue">
       <td>{{x}}</td>
    </tr> 
    </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for (var item = 0; item < 100; item++) {
  // skip every 3rd
  if ((item + 1) % 3 == 0) continue

  console.log(item)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an if condition with the remainder operator

```
for (var item = 0; item < $scope.gridImportData.data.length; item++)
{
  if(! (item % 3 === 2)){
    $scope.gridImportData[item] + (($scope.gridImportData[item] - 1) / 3)
  }
}
```

Sample demo

```js
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12]

for(let i=0; i<= arr.length-1; i++){
  if(! (i%3 === 2)){
     console.log(arr[i])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int a[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14};
int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
int i, j = 2, count = 0;
printf("The are %d elements in the array\n", n);
for (i = 2; i<n ; i++)
{
if ((i)%3 != 2)
{
a[j] = a[i];
j++;
}
else
{
count++;
}
}
printf("Number of elements removed are : %d\n", count);
printf("Resultant array is\n");
for (i = 0; i < n - count; i++)
{
printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
printf("\n");

getch();
}
```

Comment: I have sent the logic you can check that it will work definetly.

Comment: Where you copied this? He asking the solution in angularjs. not c++.

Comment: Buddy this is basic login you can use the syntax of angular thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your loop which skips all multiplies of 3.

```
for (var i=0; i<25; i % 3 === 2 ? i = i + 2 : i++)
   console.log(i)
```

Result

```
0 1 2 4 5 7 8 10 11 13 14 16 17 19 20 22 23
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are feeding an array; You can use `filter`, `indexOf`, `%` to get your desird result;

```js
const nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]

let filteredNums = nums.filter((num) => (nums.indexOf(num)+1)% 3 != 0);

console.log(filteredNums)
```

Answer (score -1):

How about,

```
int n = 100;

for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    printf("%d, ",i + (i >> 1));
}
```

Comment: Question contains tags `javascript` and `angularjs` Your question doesn't seem to be JavaScript

Comment: take the logic. Put it in java syntax.